# RS-232 signals on Bluetooth modules like HC-06, HM-10, etc

Tags: serial, bluetooth, rs232, android, windows

I would like to access any I/O pins of a bluetooth module of the likes of HC-06, HM-10 or their clones from both a Windows PC and/or Android system connected wirelessly to the module. I need Windows for one project and Android for another; they wouldn't use the same bluetooth module at the same time (that would be impossible, of course).

The 6 (or 4) pin header on the HC-06 and similar modules have nothing like a RS232 signal except for Tx and Rx, so I'd need to take those directly from the castellation in the smaller module soldered on it.

Since Windows and Android "see" the device as a serial port, I'd think the RS-232 signals like DTR, CTS, DCD, RTS, etc, should be available on the module and accessible to the remote end, but so far I've got no luck with programs like RealTerm to monitor or change any of the module's pins. I want to pass low throughput signals (e.g. low battery, turn LED on, etc.) remotely. Both the Android cell phone and the Windows PC have their own standard internal bluetooth adapters.

Something along these lines:

[image: Example connection]

Can this be done? How?

Comment: *Since Windows and Android "see" the device as a serial port, I'd think the RS-232 signals like DTR, CTS, DCD, RTS, etc, should be available* No? That's the generic bluetooth-RS232 profile you are using on the host side. It knows **nothing** about the device hardware. RTS/CTS are available on the HC-06, but that one is a hardware handshake local to the device. The driver does not meddle with it.

Comment: I realize the protocol stacks on those modules might be basic or even barely conformant, but the RFCOMM spec (current at least, 1.2 from 2012) does support the signaling. Perhaps there's another kind of API available specific to those modules?

Comment: I think so, as the modules also support SPI, USB and GPIOs. But you will need special drivers on the hosts then.